# How to update a document id of a firestore database in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Based on [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), we can only update the field value. Is there a way to update the document id value? If there is, how to do that? I only found a way to update the field value which is like this:

```
    val washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")

    washingtonRef
            .update("capital", true)
            .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!") }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e) }
```

I cannot remove the `.document("DC")` and put `.update()` after `db.collection("cities")`, it seems like they have no `.update()` option after `db.collection("cities")`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to update the document id value?

No, there is not. You cannot update a document ID or a collection name once they exist. All that data is immutable. If you need to change the ID of a document, then you should consider creating a new document with the correct document ID and deleting the old one.